# Windows XP IIS5 performance across Network

Tags: networking, windows-xp, performance, iis

Does Windows XP with IIS5 need any extra configuration to be suitable as a web server? I'm not considering using this for anything other than a web server on a small network for testing development etc.

One of the reasons I'm concerned though is that we've deployed an ASP.net application to a workstation with Windows XP, and running the application using a browser on the machine (accessing `http://localhost/myApp/page.aspx`) runs the application really quickly.
If another machine on the LAN accesses the same page (using `http://ComputerName/myApp/page.apx`) then the whole application runs noticeably slower.

The computers are connected on a gigabit switch, so I wouldn't have thought network latency or bandwidth could be an issue.

Does Windows XP need anything etc enabled or changed or network settings for it to work correctly?

EDIT: additional info: all the workstations are on a large company domain, but our workstations are all located physically on the same switch on the same subnet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We used to have our staging server deployed on XP for licensing reasons, however you need to be aware of:

- Maximum Connection Limit (10 concurrent)
- Only one website (you can get around this using `adsutil` but it's a pain)

Regarding your latency issues, it's most likely a DNS issue, and there are dozens of things that can cause this. To get around it, try accessing the server by its IP address, rather than its DNS name. (e.g. `http://192.168.0.1` instead of `http://internalserver/`). If it's full-speed using the IP address, then it's DNS related, and you'll need to search around on ServerFault for the answer (it's here somewhere)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but if I access the website using the ip address ON the server, it then runs as slow as it does from the other workstations, if I use LocalHost, it is really quick again...

Comment: The web application uses Windows Authentication, could that be an issue? Even though it runs really quickly accessed through LocalHost on the server?

Comment: +1 for the 10 concurrent connections limit.  It's real easy to miss this in testing and suddenly find your site doesn't work at production launch.

Comment: Using the Universal Tcpip.sys Patch tool, it says: Windows XP Professional SP3 (2600)
Limit: Current half open connection upper limit is 10

Comment: What happens when you access it via `127.0.0.1` on the box running the IIS?

Comment: It runs really quickly, although I had to enter my domain account details into the browser...

Comment: It sounds like it's a problem with passthrough NTLM authentication then. Do you want it to prompt each user for a username/password? Or do you want to permit anonymous access?

Comment: It's set to be integrated authentication as the user accounts are based on there AD domain account. I was surprised to be prompted for a username and password as I've logged onto the machine with the same details

Answer (score 0):

It may help to set processor scheduling to [Background Services](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308417).